# I Need Subfloor Help Please

Tags: subfloor

I need some advice please. I am redoing the floors in my parent's house. I need the floors as level as possible because we are going to install LVP flooring. The living room had carpet, but the kitchen had tile. The kitchen has a 3/4” subfloor and a 5/8” layer of underlayment and a 1/8” layer of underlayment on top of it. After tearing out the tile, and there is a 5/8” difference from the kitchen floor to the living room floor. My question is. Can I install another layer of 5/8” plywood underlayment on top of the other layers to make the kitchen floor even with the living room floor, and if I do, is there any special way I should install it? Do I need to screw directly into the joist or the subfloor?

[image]

2nd Question is. When tearing up the tile, a small section of the 1/8’” underlayment ripped up. Do I need to patch it if I install a new layer of plywood on top of it, and if I need to prepare the 1/8” underlayment, what’s the best way to go about repairing that small section?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I've attached photos showing the damaged 1/8" underlayment and the 5/8" height difference in the floors.

Comment: Why not put a transition strip between the two rooms? A **lot** less work and expense than raising a room 5/8".

Comment: What's the subfloor—concrete?  (The higher floor kinda looks like wood, but it's dark like concrete.)

Comment: They are both wood, the kitchen floor just has a 1/8" layer of underlayment on it. I believe its sound tampering material.

Answer (score 2):

Repair the small section of 1/8 with [floor filler](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Patching-Compound/3011841?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-3011841-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjw6vyiBhB_EiwAQJRophAouMY4gGPYbc-nipeGl1j55HmCT-5AEGu1FDuvHECvrDnoCiBawRoCv2sQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Then screw your 5/8 ply down with 2 inch screws. Construction adhesive can be added for a floor that is less likely to creak, pop or squeek.

The LVP is very forgiving. Still an additional underlayment such as [Quiet walk](https://www.lowes.com/pl/Quietwalk-For-use-with-vinyl-plank--Flooring-underlayment-Flooring/4294418636?refinement=4294896583,2108561341) or similar, helps keep the noise down and the feeling a bit softer, also mitigates small imperfections.

Comment: Do I need to screw directly into the floor joyce?

Comment: @ I am Not A Carpenter,  no you do not

Comment: When you say floor filler, do you mean self-leveling concrete?

Comment: No,  there are pre mixed products that are like drywall compound, but cure much faster and dry harder.  Most home supply stores have some type in the flooring section.  Also click on  floor filler in my answer.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you so much for all your help on this.

Comment: You are welcome, good luck.